# Flask error: werkzeug.routing.BuildError

Tags: python, flask

I modify the login of flaskr sample app, the first line get error.  But www.html is in the template dir.

```
return redirect(url_for('www'))
#return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

display error：

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError

BuildError: ('www', {}, None)
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

`return redirect(url_for('www'))` would work if you have a function somewhere else like this:

```
@app.route('/welcome')
def www():
    return render_template('www.html')
```

`url_for` looks for a function, you pass it the *name* of the function you are wanting to call.  Think of it like this:

```
@app.route('/login')
def sign_in():
    for thing in login_routine:
        do_stuff(thing)
    return render_template('sign_in.html')

@app.route('/new-member')
def welcome_page():
    flash('welcome to our new members')
    flash('no cussing, no biting, nothing stronger than gin before breakfast')
    return redirect(url_for('sign_in')) # not 'login', not 'sign_in.html'
```

You could also do `return redirect('/some-url')`, if that is easier to remember.  It is also possible that what you want, given your first line, is just `return render_template('www.html')`.

And also, not from shuaiyuancn's comment below, if you are using blueprints, `url_for` should be invoked as `url_for('blueprint_name.func_name')` *Note you aren't passing the object, rather the string.* [See documentation here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#building-urls).

Comment: +1 for a very clear example ... and for "nothing stronger than gin before breakfast"

Comment: I've got same problem with `Blueprint` =/

Comment: For a blueprint, replace the @app with the name of your blueprint. @app.route('xx') becomes @blueprint_name.route('xx')

Comment: with blueprints it should be `url_for('blue_print.func_name')` as indicated in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/#building-urls

Comment: I think @shuaiyuancn's comment deserves mention---apparently it's my mistake. Leaving it as a comment tends to bury it in SO's folding algorithm when it could be useful to others.

Comment: If, like me, you still couldn't get this to work, verify that you name your Blueprint consistently. I was using `foo = Blueprint('bar')`, and wondering why `foo` was not building correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `def www():` is already defined (as suggested by unmounted's awesome answer), this error can also be thrown *if you are using a blueprint which has not been registered.*

Make sure to register these when `app` is first instantiated.  For me it was done like this:

```
from project.app.views.my_blueprint import my_blueprint
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='{}/templates'.format(app_path), static_folder='{}/static'.format(app_path))
app.register_blueprint(my_blueprint)
```

**And within** `my_blueprint.py`:

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint
from flask_cors import CORS

my_blueprint = Blueprint('my_blueprint', __name__, url_prefix='/my-page')
CORS(my_blueprint)


@metric_retriever.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', page_title='My Page!')
```

Comment: I specifically experienced this when working with a pytest decorator without using `wraps` from the `functools` library. Added blueprints and voila, problem solved. [Flask functools ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114296/why-does-flasks-url-for-throw-an-error-when-using-a-decorator-on-that-item-in-p)

Answer (score 3):

I came across this error

> BuildError: ('project_admin', {}, None)

when I had a call like

`return redirect(url_for('project_admin'))`

in which I was trying to reference the `project_admin` function within my Blueprint.  To resolve the error, I added a dot before the name of the function, like this:

`return redirect(url_for('.project_admin'))`

and voila, my problem was solved.

Comment: I was having this issue and for whatever reason adding the dot solved it for me as well. I didn't even need to keep the dot in afterward - it's like it kicked Flask/Blueprint/Something and forced it to fix itself. Thanks again.