# Why does Flask's url_for throw an error when using a decorator on that item in Python?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, build-error

I am creating a Python Flask app and created the decorator and views below. The decorator works great when viewing the index, but when you logout and it redirects using the `url_for` index it throws a builderror. Why would

```
def logged_in(fn):
    def decorator():
        if 'email' in session:
            return fn()
        else:
            return render_template('not-allowed.html', page="index")
    return decorator


@app.route('/')
@logged_in
def index():
    email = session['email']    
    return render_template('index.html', auth=True, page="index", marks=marks)

@app.route('/sign-out')
def sign_out():
    session.pop('email')
    print(url_for('index'))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Any ideas? The error is: `BuildError: ('index', {}, None)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem here is that `decorator()` function which you return has different name than the function it is decorating, so the URL builder can't find your `index` view.  You need to use `wraps()` decorator from `functools` module to copy the name of the original function.  Another problem (which you still have to encounter) is that you don't accept the arguments in your decorator and pass it to the original function.  Here's is the corrected decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def logged_in(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'email' in session:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # IMO it's nicer to abort here and handle it in errorhandler.
            abort(401)
    return decorator
```

---

*A bit more explanations*: in Python decorator is a function which takes another function as its argument and returns a function as its result. So the following

```
@logged_in
def index(): pass
```

is essentially identical to

```
def index(): pass
index = logged_in(index)
```

The problem in this case was that what your `logged_in` decorator returns is not the original function, but a wrapper (called `decorator` in your code), which wraps the original function. This wrapper has a different name (`decorator`) than the original function it is wrapping. Now `app.route()` decorator, which you call after `logged_in`, sees this new function and uses its name (`decorator`) to register a route for it. Here lies the problem: you want the decorated function to have the same name (`index`), so it could be used in `url_for()` to get a route for it. That's why you need to copy the name manually

```
decorator.__name__ = fn.__name__
```

or better use `update_wrapper` and `wraps` helpers from `functools` module, which do that and even more for you.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what it means to have a "different signature"?

Comment: Thanks for asking, you made me realize that I was using this term incorrectly myself. What I _really_ meant was "different function name". I'll update the answer to use the correct term and add more explanations. And if you want to learn more about decorators and "call signature" problem, head to the excellent [documentation](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html) of `decorator` module, as I feel that this is out of this question's scope.